# Testing for an empty parameter in a SAS Macro

Tags: sas, sas-macro

For example, i have a macro program

```
%macro test(parameter1= , parameter2=, parameter3=);
  DATA data_gender;
  SET data_input(WHERE=(gender=parameter3));
  RUN;
  .....
%mend;
```

Basically, i made a selection of observations using the parameter3 (Male or Female). Now i want to create a third option: to keep both observations in Male and Female when the parameter3 is empty (without declaring the value of this parameter).

```
%test(parameter1=xxx , parameter2=yyy, parameter3=);
```

Can you tell me how can i do that please?

Answer (score 4):

For this answer I will cite Chang Chung's seminal paper, ["Is This Macro Parameter Blank"](http://changchung.com/download/022-2009.pdf), as it is excellent and goes into great detail about your options here.

The "best" option follows (ie, using the recommended method from the paper above).  Note the initial `%test` macro doesn't return any rows for the blank parameter, while the second `%test2` does.

There are simpler ways to test for a macro parameter being blank that work in most cases, and read the paper for more details about the simpler options.

```
%macro test(parameter1= , parameter2=, sex=);
  DATA data_gender;
  SET sashelp.class(where=(sex="&sex."));
  RUN;
%mend;

%test(sex=M);
%test(sex=F);
%test(sex=);

%macro test2(parameter1= , parameter2=, sex=);
  DATA data_gender;
  SET sashelp.class(
    %if %sysevalf(%superq(sex) ne,boolean) %then %do;
        where=(sex="&sex.")
        %end;
    );
  RUN;
%mend;

%test2(sex=M);
%test2(sex=F);
%test2(sex=);
```

Comment: Thanks Joe it works. But i don't understand the functions %sysevalf and %superq . Doesn't %sysevalf returns a value 0 or 1? Why it can stands alone in the condition bloc? How can it works if i say (if 1 then do...).

Comment: 0 or 1 is false or true in SAS.  Read the linked paper for more details on those specific functions (or, if you still don't understand, feel free to ask a new question about how those functions work!)

Answer (score 4):

Agree with Joe's answer.  One good point they make in the paper is they are testing for blank, and their test will return true whether a parameter is null or has blanks in it.  Sometimes it is useful have a test that differentiates between a parameter that is null and one that has blanks.  The paper mentions `%length(%superq( ))` as a possible test for null. For example below, this allows you to specify a blank value for sex, and get a different result than you do when sex is null.

```
data class;
  set sashelp.class;
  if _n_=1 then sex='';
run;

%macro test2(parameter1= , parameter2=, sex=);
  DATA data_gender;
  SET class(
            %if %length(%superq(sex)) %then %do;
              where=(sex="&sex.")
            %end;
           );
  RUN;
%mend;

%test2(sex=)
%test2(sex=%str( ))
```