# SAS remove the specified word when it starts or ends the expression

Tags: regex, sas

I am writing a macro variable that aims at producing a valid SQL WHERE clause as specified by user in prompts. Assume we have 3 variables X, Y, Z, and so on. User may specify the filter for every variable and macro variable looks like:

```
a = x eq 1 and y eq 1 and z eq 1;
```

which is then proceeded to the WHERE clause.
But if user specifies only, let's say' filter for Y it looks like:

```
a =  and y eq 1 and
```

And I would like it to look like:

```
a = y eq 1
```

That is why I would like to somehow remove the operand 'AND' when it starts or ends the expression (it may start or end it multiple times, e.g. if we fitler only Z variable it looks like):

```
a =  and and and z eq 1
```

I suppose it could be easily done with regular expressions but since I'm new to it, is there anyone willing to help me ? ;)

Comment: You've got good solutions already.  Depending on sophistication of your users, sometimes you can just have a single WHERE parameter, and let users write whatever expression they want as the value of a single prompt, rather than passing values for each part of the expression.  For sophisticated users, this gives them more flexibility, of course at cost of requiring them to write the correct expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slight rework of @DirkHorsten's technique.  This simply organizes the code in a slightly different manner so that the SQL statement can be more easily read.  In my opinion, the SQL statement is the important piece of code that you would like readers to understand (so let's keep it simple!), while the building of the where clause is just a side-note.  This can be a valuable approach, especially as your SQL statements become more complex.

Approach 1, a single variable for all filters:

```
%macro getMyData(xValue=, yValue=, zValue=);
    %local and_filters;

    * THE BORING IMPLEMENTATION DETAILS ARE KEPT SEPARATE;
    %let and_filters = ;
    %if "&xValue" ne "" %then %do;
        %let and_filters = &and_filters and sex eq "&xValue";
    %end;
    %if "&yValue" ne "" %then %do;
        %let and_filters = &and_filters and age eq &yValue;
    %end;
    %if "&zValue" ne "" %then %do;
        %let and_filters = &and_filters and height eq &zValue;
    %end;

    * THE IMPORTANT PIECE OF CODE IS EASY TO READ;
    proc sql;
        select * 
        from sashelp.class
        where 1 &and_filters
        ;
    quit;
%mend;
```

Approach 2, individual variables for each filter:

```
%macro getMyData(xValue=, yValue=, zValue=);
    %local and_sex_filter and_age_filter and_height_filter;

    * THE BORING IMPLEMENTATION DETAILS ARE KEPT SEPARATE;
    %let and_sex_filter    = ;
    %let and_age_filter    = ;
    %let and_height_filter = ;

    %if "&xValue" ne "" %then %do;
        %let and_sex_filter = and sex eq "&xValue";
    %end;
    %if "&yValue" ne "" %then %do;
        %let and_age_filter = and age eq &yValue;
    %end;
    %if "&zValue" ne "" %then %do;
        %let and_height_filter = and height eq &zValue;
    %end;

    * THE IMPORTANT PIECE OF CODE IS EASY TO READ;
    proc sql;
        select * 
        from sashelp.class
        where 1 
         &and_sex_filter
         &and_age_filter
         &and_height_filter
        ;
    quit;
%mend;
```

Comment: For the record, I think Joe's solution is the way to go.  The above approach may be more useful in more complex examples.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're doing this via macro parameters, this is easier to do by supplying a default.

```
%macro filter(x=1,y=1,z=1);
  where &x. and &y. and &z.;
%mend filter;
```

1 is "true", so it acts (along with "AND") as a left-out argument.

If you only want to pass values (not the full equality), then you can also do this:

```
%macro filter(x=x, y=y, z=z);
  where x=&x. and y=&y. and z=&z.;
%mend filter;
```

`x=x` is always true in SAS, but if you're passing through to SQL Server or Oracle and might have nulls this will not work (as `null=null` is false in SQL Server or Oracle).

Comment: OK, but now the user has to specify equalities instead of values.

Comment: @DirkHorsten Given the question, I think that's what was done anyway.  Look at the 'nothing specified' code: it doesn't include `x=`...

Comment: And it would be just as easy to have `x` be a value, and then have `x=x` as your default.  Variables are always equal to themselves [ in SAS, not in sql server of course].

Comment: What if your x value is not manually coded by the user, but calculated? What if it is an optional prompt for a stored process or a SAS EG program?

Comment: ?  I'm not sure what you're getting at.  I'm suggesting including a default so that if it's not included it will have a value that makes it automatically true.  I don't see how any of that has any effect.

Comment: You are right. Your second trial is flexible, and it has the advantage of working in open code too (in contrast with that of Vasillji and me

Answer (score 1):

```
%macro getMyData(xValue=, yValue=, zValue=);
    proc sql;
        select * 
        from   sashelp.class
        where 
            %if %length(&xValue) %then %do;
                sex = "&xValue." and
            %end;
            %if %length(&yValue) %then %do;
                age = &yValue. and
            %end;
            %if %length(&zValue) %then %do;
                height >= &zValue. and
            %end;
            1;
    quit;
%mend;
Title 'Females';
%getMyData(xValue=F);

Title '12 year';
%getMyData(yValue=12);

Title 'Large males';
%getMyData(xValue=M, zValue=60);
```

Comment: I'd be careful about using `%length(&yvalue)` here, particularly if it's not just values you're passing but possibly expressions - that's one of the most likely places to get things that will not work with that.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31686223/testing-for-an-empty-parameter-in-a-sas-macro/31686698#31686698 mentions an excellent paper that covers this in great detail.  Otherwise, this is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a little known "where also" expression. Appended "where also" expressions logically equal to AND operator for each WHERE clause and you can user "where also" as your first WHERE clause without any issues to your code.

If you have a macro like that:

```
%MACRO get_data;

data want;
    set have;
    where a = x eq 1 and y eq 1 and z eq 1;
RUN;

%MEND;
```

You can rewrite to someting like:

%MACRO get_data;

```
data want;
    set have;

    %IF &X ne %THEN
        %DO;
            where also &x eq 1;
        %END;

    %IF &Y ne %THEN
        %DO;
            where also &y eq 1;
        %END;

    %IF &Z ne %THEN
        %DO;
            where also &z eq 1;
        %END;
RUN;

%MEND;
```

Before you test the code, you need to at least initialise the macro variables. 
You could do it with something like that:

```
%IF %symexist(&Z)=0 %THEN %LET Z = ;
```

Comment: You can only have one where clause, so now the user can only fill in one criterion

Comment: @DirkHorsten You can have as many as you like. I use code like that all the time. Also see this: http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/Where_also

Comment: Thanks, never realized I can have multiple where clauses in a data step, but the question was about PROC SQL. There you can not.

Comment: Right - this doesn't work in PROC SQL unfortunately, that was exactly what I thought immediately as well otherwise...

Comment: Yeah, WHERE ALSO changed my life when I first saw Don Henderson point it out somewhere.  Makes DATA STEP / PROC life much easier (but not PROC SQL, sadly).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all,
I have already figured out a similar structure as @Robert Penridge, but I appriciate all of the answers :) Thanks!

PS. I also was not familiar with WHERE ALSO - may prove useful in the future:)