# SAS Error: A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric operand is required

Tags: if-statement, macros, sas, eval

I have a macro with the following macro variables: cat_var, model, validate.

When I enter the following call the macro runs fine:

```
%models(cat_var=mommy dadmy,model=age readhr mommy dadmy,validate=no);
```

But then when I enter this call:

```
%models(cat_var=mommy dadmy,model=age readhr mommy dadmy age*readhr,validate=no);
```

I get this error message:

***A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition
where a numeric operand is required. The condition was: (&validate =) or
((&cat_var =) and (&model =)) or ((&cat_var ^=) and (&model =))***

Therefore, I believe I have isolated the issue to the following code I have written:

```
%if (&validate =) or ((&cat_var =) and (&model =)) or ((&cat_var ^=) and (&model =)) %then 
%put ERROR: One or more inputs are missing. Check to make sure all macro variables have an input where necessary. (It is not necessary to have cat_var inputs);
```

The logic I intended for this code to use is as follows:

If validate is missing an input OR (cat_var AND model are missing an input) OR (cat_var is NOT missing an input AND model is missing an input) then display an error message.

This code worked as I expected until I entered a * symbol in the model input. Is this what's screwing it up? And how can I fix this?

Comment: `if validate = or` is not valid syntax in any language.

Comment: Yes. I'm aware. It still isn't valid syntax. It isn't changed by `&validate` being a variable. Unless `or` is a variable that `&validate` can be compared against (which it clearly isn't), the comparison is invalid. You can't compare a variable against a logical operator using an equals sign in any language I've ever seen. Say it in words. Pretend `&validate` is a dog. *if Dog equals or (Cat or Frog)*. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: As far as my understanding goes, SAS recognizes that if there is no argument on the other side of the equal sign then it is evaluating the variable equal to null (or missing). It probably looks nicer if I were to write it this way: `(&validate=) or`.
However, I have run the code both ways and it works. The only thing that is causing it to freak out is when that * symbol is introduced. What I'm asking for is potentially another way for me to to evaluate missing inputs because clearly something is going buggy when that * is introduced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `%eval()` function can also evaluate integer arithmetic you are getting the error because of the introduction of the arithmetic operator.

If you want to test if a macro variable is empty or blank then see this question.
[Testing for an empty parameter in a SAS Macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31686223/testing-for-an-empty-parameter-in-a-sas-macro)

Comment: Thanks for directing me to that answer!